# Google Sheets: Dynamic Generated IMPORTRANGE formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a drop down cell in column A with the names of the tabs of another workbook.
In column B, I will manually input a row #.

I want to use the worksheet name from Column `A`, and the row information from column `B` in a formula to look up information.

The formula I am currently using is:

`=IMPORTRANGE("heresmyworkbookwebaddress", "Drink!A2")`

What I am trying to do is: make it so that `Drink` is generated from the drop down menu cell, and the `2` from `A2` is generated from the information contained in the cell from my `B` column. The `A` in `A2` should always stay as `A`.

Is there any way to do this?
Is there an easier way to pull information from another workbook?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to concatenate the second part of your formula like this:

`=IMPORTRANGE("heresmyworkbookwebaddress", *cellcontainingdropdown*&"A"&*B-cell*)`

Instead of "*cellcontainingdropdown*" you enter the cell.
Instead of "*B-Cell*" you insert the rownumber of column B that you need.

Depending on the format of your cell containing the workbook names you have to use "`&!A&`" instead of "`&A&`" if those are not used.